# C# Monogame Performance when Drawing Thousands of SpriteBatch.DrawString()

Tags: c#, monogame

I'm currently creating a large map, that consists of a lot of rectangles (33,844), that all have a unique name (label), which I'm drawing on top of them using a SpriteFont.

Drawing all of the rectangles takes no performance hit at all. But, as soon as I try to write all of their labels with DrawString(), my performance goes into the dumps.

In my head, I would like to draw all my rectangles and text to one texture all at once, and only have to keep redrawing that entire finished texture. My issue is, this is an enormous map, and some of the coordinates for the rectangles are very high (example: one slot's x is 14869 and y is 23622), and they're far bigger than a Texture2D allows.

Since this is a map, I really only need to draw the entire thing once, and then allow the user to scroll/move around it. There's no need for me to continually redraw all of the individual rectangles and their labels.

Does anyone have experience with this type of situation?

Comment: You are thinking of this the wrong way round, you need to only draw the part the user can see, however you do indeed have to draw it every frame. Noone can read 30,000 labels on one page... only draw the region which can be seen at one time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to only render the labels that you can see on the screen and if you can zoom back far enough, just don't render them.

Textrendering is expensive, since it is basically creating a rectangle to draw on for every character in the font and then applying the same RGBA texture to it. So depending on the number of characters you write, the number of rectangles increases. This means four new vertices per character.

Depending on what you write you could simply create a texture with the text already on it and render that, but it won't be very dynamic.

EDIT: I need to clarify something.

> There's no need for me to continually redraw all of the individual rectangles and their labels.

This is wrong. You have to draw the whole thing every frame. Sure, it doesn't increase memorywise, but it still is a lot to render and you will need to render it every frame.

But as I said: Try to only render the labels and the rectangles that collide with the screenboundaries, then you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I'm going to give this a shot and will update if I can get it to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve your problem.

You can either render your map to a RenderTarget(2D/3D) or you can cull the rectangles/text that are offscreen. However, I am not 100% sure that RenderTargets can go as large as you would need, but you could always segment your map into multiple smaller RenderTargets.

From more information on RenderTargets, you might want to check out RB Whitaker's article on them, http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/render-to-texture

Culling, in case you are familiar with the term when used in this context, means to only render what is visible to the end-user. There are various ways that culling can be implemented. This does however require you to have already implemented a camera (or some type of view region) and you perform a basic axis-aligned bounding box collision (AABB collision, which MonoGame's Rectangle supports out of the box) of the rectangles against the camera's viewport and only render it if there is a collision.

A basic implementation of culling would look something like this:

```
Rectangle myRect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 48, 32);
public void DrawMapItem(SpriteBatch batch, Rectangle viewRegion)
{
    if (viewRegion.Contains(myRect))
    {
        //Render your object here with the SpriteBatch
    }
}
```

Where 'viewRegion' is the area of you world that the camera/end-user can actually see.

You can also combine the two methods, and render the map to multiple render targets, and then cull the render targets.

Hope this helps!